# Arduino HX711 load cell lots of drift

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, library

I am trying to make [this](https://www.robotshop.com/ca/en/micro-load-cell-50-kg.html?gclid=Cj0KCQiA9OiPBhCOARIsAI0y71COwRpGv_NHrT68xsmCCZL6BTN8nYfXpjPnluj4AhdVfCZT5KRI-xcaAjk8EALw_wcB) 50kg load cell work with [this](https://www.amazon.ca/-/fr/gp/product/B07MTYT95R/ref=ox_sc_rp_title_rp_1?smid=&psc=1&pf_rd_p=9e23f442-1cd8-4ea2-a936-d77b2d58e3f5&pd_rd_wg=gbmVg&pd_rd_i=B07MTYT95R&pd_rd_w=Ik5oB&pd_rd_r=d4e1d9b9-e72f-453c-b6d9-3bd255d99539) HX711 chip. I currently have the following connections :

- Load cell red -> E+
- Load cell black -> E-
- Load cell white -> A-
- Load cell green -> A+

I am using [this](https://github.com/bogde/HX711) library and this code :

```
#include "HX711.h"

#define calibration_factor -7050

HX711 scale;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  scale.begin(2, 3);
  scale.set_scale(calibration_factor);
  scale.tare();
}


void loop() 
{
  Serial.println(scale.get_units(1));
  delay(100);
}
```

The load cell appears to register load changes but the value is constantly going up (or down if the calibration_factor is positive). The value change rate is very high (from 0 to 300 in a couple of seconds).

Edit : I have 2 load cells and both of them do the same thing (with different HX711 chips).

Edit 2 : My question is : has anyone experienced this ? Or does anyone have an idea as to why this is happening ?

Comment: what is your specific question?

Comment: Oups ! I edited the question @jsotola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to solder all the wires, now the drift seems to be very minimal or non existant.